# Visual Studio Code Debugger - What is app.js?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have created an AngularJS 1.4 project using the [gulp-angular](https://github.com/swiip/generator-gulp-angular#readme) yeoman generator.

I'd like to be able to launch it debug mode in Visual Studio Code. However, most examples of the launch.json file that I have seen on the web suggest that one sets the "program" value to "app.js"

```
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "app.js",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
```

but the Yeoman generator has not created a file with that name.

What file should I enter here? The file where the Angular modules are defined? The file with the routing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think app.js is just a file name and you can give any name. its a just for base js like for to include all modules which are used in application.

For example:
in your app.js

```
var MyApplicationName = angular.module('myModuleName', [ 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.expandable', 'ui.grid.pinning']);
```

And in my other MyController.js controller

```
MyApplicationName .controller('ControllerName', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', function ($scope, $http, $uibModal)
```

And in my other AnotherControler.js controller

MyApplicationName .controller('2ndControllerName', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', function ($scope, $http, $uibModal)

Hope this help you :)

Comment: That was it. Pointed it to the file with the module definitions. Thanks.